# Return how many words are into a cell

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone help me with an advice regarding how to return with VBA the number of words from a cell?

In Excel I use `C2=LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ",""))+1`, but it seems in VBA the "`SUBSTITUTE`" function it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: That formula works assuming that the cell isn't empty and doesn't contain multiple spaces between words.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Split on the space character and get the upper boundary of the resulting array.

```
dim numchars as long
numchars = ubound(split(range("b2").value2, chr(32)))+1
debug.print numchars
```

1 is added as VBA arrays have a default start (lbound) of zero.

BTW, the VBA equivalent of the worksheet SUBSTITUTE function is Replace.

Comment: Why `Value2` rather than `Value` ??

Comment: `Value2` does not have extraneous information (date, currency, etc) and is retrieved slightly faster. You might notice if you did a million of these.

Comment: This       assumes       that       there       is       only       one       space between       each        word.

Comment: @Comintern - Yes that is true but it does duplicate the OP's worksheet function method. It could be `worksheetfunction.Trim(range("b2").value2)` as the worksheet TRIM will change interim double spacing to single while VBA's Trim will not.

Comment: Woah, there's a lot to learn in this otherwise "standard" function. Nicely done Jeeped and thanks for your comments too!

Comment: This `worksheetfunction.Trim()` tip is definitely something to remember. Thank you for that.

Comment: Nice - nearly failed to get this by being distracted by *numchars* naming.

Answer (score 0):

A `Regexp` option to ensure only valid words are returned, and ignores any whitespace issues to boot.

```
Function NumWords(strIn As String) As Long
Dim objRegex As Object
Dim objRegMC As Object
Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With objRegex
    .Pattern = "\b[a-z]+\b"
    .Global = True
    If .test(LCase$(strIn)) Then
        Set objRegMC = .Execute(strIn)
        NumWords = objRegMC.Count
    Else
        NumWords = 0
        End If
End With
End Function
```